# Get differential equation with separable variables from one in symmetric form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The 
There is the equation:
$$\frac{-dx}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{dy}{\sin^2 y + z \cos x \sin y} = \frac{dz}{z \sin(x+y) \cos(x-y) + z^2 \cos x \cos y}$$

The main idea of how to solve given equation is to find **multiplier** for some of the fractions and get equation with separable variables, i.e. in form: 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)g(y)$$

Please, provide some ideas of what the **multiplier** is. 
*(There should be two **multipliers**, but any help is needed)*

Comment: I think you need three multipliers to get three equations.

Comment: @Vasya no, only two are needed

Comment: So $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$ or all of them are functions of another independent variable?

Comment: @Vasya, $y$ and $z$ depend on $x$, $x$ is independent

Comment: Then you are right, two multipliers will do. The only simplification I see now is $\sin(x+y)\cos(x-y)=\sin x \cos x+ \sin y \cos y$

Comment: @Vasya, I've already tried this unfortunately, but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution.

1. There should be two multipliers: the second fraction **(2)** sholud be multiplied by $z \cos y$, the third one **(3)** by $\sin y$
2. Then we subtract **(3)** from **(2)** and equate to the first fraction **(1)**.
3. Result is: $$\frac{z \cos y dy - \sin y dz}{z \sin x \cos x \sin y} = \frac{dx}{\cos^2 x}$$
4. After multipling by $\sin x \cos x$ we get regular diffenetial equation with separable variables. After solving we express $z$ and get: $$z = \frac{\cos x \ sin y}{c}$$ (c is constant)
5. Then we substitute $z$ to **(2)** and equte the result to **(1)**. We get equation with separable variables again.
6. It's solution is: $$\tan x + \frac{x}{c} = \cot y + c_1$$ ($c$ and $c_1$ are constants)
7. All in all the solution of the original equation is:
   $$
   \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{h}
   z = \frac{\cos x \ sin y}{c} \\ 
   \tan x + \frac{x}{c} = \cot y + c_1
   \end{array}
   \right. 
   $$
   ($c$ and $c_1$ are constants)